# Get server certificate from failed connection attempt with HttpClient 4.2

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm currently adding a https download functionality to my application using the Apache HttpClient, specifically version 4.2.3.

I want to get my hands on the server certificate chain if the certificate validation fails. The exception that gets thrown `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` has no fields that provide any information.

```
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
} catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
    // retrieve server certificate here
}
```

There is a way by injecting a `TrustManager` (to capture the certificates) into the `SSLContext` and recreating the `SSLContext`, `SSLSocketFactory` and `HttpClient` for each request. But, I would like to be able to reuse those instances for multiple, possible parallel, requests.

Comment: The way that you've subsequently described, via the an `SSLSocket` is the only way I know of. If the `HttpClient` somehow offers this ability, I'm unaware of it. Basically I create a dummy `TrustManager` that retains the certificate-chain inside of `checkServerTrusted`, then if the handshake throws a cert-validation error, it processes the obtained cert-chain. I can show some code in an answer if you want, but it really seems like you already know how to do it this way, and want to do it through the HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks, I already have it implemented that way. I'm just wondering if this can be done by reusing the HttpClient or at least the SSLContext, SSLSocketFactory and TrustManager. The reason for that is to get features like connection reuse/caching working on the httpclient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used HC 4.3 for this example but should work exactly the same way with HC 4.2 though I would recommend upgrading

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    TrustManagerFactory tmfactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmfactory.init((KeyStore) null);
    TrustManager[] tms = tmfactory.getTrustManagers();
    if (tms != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
            final TrustManager tm = tms[i];
            if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                tms[i] = new TrustManagerDelegate((X509TrustManager) tm);
            }
        }
    }
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tms, null);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSslcontext(sslContext)
            .build();
    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
        try {
            // do something usefull
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } catch (SSLException ex) {
        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof MyCertificateException) {
            X509Certificate[] chain = ((MyCertificateException) cause).getChain();
            for (X509Certificate cert: chain) {
                System.out.println(cert);
            }
        }
    }
}

static class TrustManagerDelegate implements X509TrustManager {

    private final X509TrustManager trustManager;

    TrustManagerDelegate(final X509TrustManager trustManager) {
        super();
        this.trustManager = trustManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
        this.trustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            this.trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        } catch (CertificateException ex) {
            throw new MyCertificateException(chain, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return this.trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
    }

}

static class MyCertificateException extends CertificateException {

    private final X509Certificate[] chain;

    MyCertificateException(final X509Certificate[] chain, final CertificateException ex) {
        super(ex);
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getChain() {
        return chain;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, I should have come up with that by myself ;) Thanks @oleg

Comment: Just an addition to this. This is platform-dependent behavior. It depends on the internal SSL implementation to set the cause correctly. E.g. it does not work on Android 4.4.

Comment: You probably want to say this behavior is JSSE provider dependent rather than platform dependent. Moreover, Androids provider not propagating the root cause sounds like a defect too me and not 'platform-dependent behavior'. In any way the cert chain could be propagated to the caller by using a custom connection factory and HttpContext